# Composing errors in Rust : concating results on Ok

Tags: error-handling, rust

I have following code. It works.

But i am more interested in writing `make_tea` where i call two functions : `get_milk_from_cow` and `pour_milk`. They both return `Result<String, TeaError>`.

How can i compose them so that i can keep concating `String`s if they succeed otherwise return error.

```
enum TeaError {
    NoMilk,
    NoCup,
    NoCow,
    NoGas,
    NoSomething,
}

fn get_milk_from_cow(cow: bool) -> Result<String, TeaError> {
    if cow {
        Ok(String::from("get milk from cow"))
    } else {
        Err(TeaError::NoCow)
    }
}

fn pour_milk(milk: bool) -> Result<String, TeaError> {
    if milk {
        Ok(String::from("poured milk"))
    } else {
        Err(TeaError::NoMilk)
    }
}

fn make_tea() -> Result<String, TeaError> {
    let mut process = String::new();
    let step_cow = get_milk_from_cow(true)?;
    let step_milk = pour_milk(true)?;
    process.push_str(step_cow.as_str());
    process.push_str(step_milk.as_str());
    Ok(process)
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn attemp_tea_one() {
        match pour_milk(false) {
            Err(v) => match v {
                TeaError::NoMilk => assert!(true),
                _ => assert!(false)
            },
            Ok(_) => assert!(false)
        };
    }

    #[test]
    fn attemp_tea_two() {
        match make_tea() {
            Err(_) => assert!(false),
            Ok(_) => assert!(true)
        };
    }
}
```

I tried :

```
process.push_str(get_milk_from_cow(true)?
       .push_str(pour_milk(true)?.as_str()))
```

but it gives :

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/errors.rs:27:22
   |
27 |     process.push_str(get_milk_from_cow(true)?.push_str(pour_milk(true)?.as_str()));
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected &str, found ()
   |
   = note: expected type `&str`
              found type `()`
```

as `push_str` does not return string.

**Edit:**

```
fn append(s1: String, s2: String) -> String {
    s1 + s2.as_str()
}
fn make_tea() -> Result<String, TeaError> {
    let process = append(get_milk_from_cow(true)?,
                         pour_milk(true)?);
    Ok(process)
}
```

so, i can do `append(append(funcA(), funcB()), funcC())` and so on..
I am still learning about lifetimes and think about whether `append` can still be improved in memory allocation.

Comment: How would you do it without `Result` in the picture, i.e. if `get_milk_from_cow` and `pour_milk` returned `String`s?

Comment: @user4815162342 `pour_milk` is symbolic of any function that can fail.

Comment: My point is that the problem is not in those functions failing (the `?` operator is taking care of that), but in `push_str` returning `()`. Please show us how you would concatenate the strings when `Result` is not present, to better understand what you would like to achieve with `Result`.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks for your question, i think i have found (maybe inefficient) solution, pondering over your question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does redundant work on the starred lines:

```
fn make_tea() -> Result<String, TeaError> {
*   let mut process = String::new();
    let step_cow = get_milk_from_cow(true)?;
    let step_milk = pour_milk(true)?;
*   process.push_str(step_cow.as_str());
    process.push_str(step_milk.as_str());
    Ok(process)
}
```

`process.push_str(step_cow.as_str())` just makes an unneeded copy of `step_cow`. Instead, try

```
fn make_tea() -> Result<String, TeaError> {
    let mut process = get_milk_from_cow(true)?;
    process.push_str(&pour_milk(true)?);
    Ok(process)
}
```

or, more conveniently,

```
fn make_tea() -> Result<String, TeaError> {
    Ok(get_milk_from_cow(true)? + &pour_milk(true)?)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First things first: there appears to be nothing wrong with your code above, but I'll be assuming that you are looking for something more idiomatic.

Although requiring slightly more memory than your approach, the most elegant way to concatenate results of strings is this:

```
fn make_tea() -> Result<String, TeaError> {
    vec![get_milk_from_cow(true), pour_milk(true)].into_iter()
        .collect()
}
```

[Playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=5891d1dd6a5d3364bbb654c8cbdfdd05&version=undefined)

Explanation:

- The vector is consumed into an iterator of `Result<String, TeaError>` (owned, not references).
- `collect` then relies on two implementations of `FromIterator`:

  - `impl<A, E, V> FromIterator<Result<A, E>> for Result<V, E> 
    where V: FromIterator<A>` produces a result containing either the result of building `A` from an iterator of `T` or the first error retrieved from the iterator. This is like turning an iterator of results into a result with a collected iterator.
  - `impl FromIterator<String> for String` concatenates all strings into an owned string

So, as soon as you already have an iterator that turns your process into a sequence of independent operations, you can just `collect` them.

Now, in order to prevent subsequent operations from being called after an error is found, then it's easier to stick to the `?` operator.

```
fn make_tea() -> Result<String, TeaError> {
    Ok(vec![get_milk_from_cow(true)?, pour_milk(true)?].into_iter()
        .collect())
}
```

[Playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=425fc4fea0742f821b7ec850c18abdbb&version=undefined)

---

The vector had to be created because arrays do not provide iterators of owned elements (`&T` instead of `T`). However, we can go around that with an extra mapping:

```
fn make_tea() -> Result<String, TeaError> {
    Ok([get_milk_from_cow(true)?, pour_milk(true)?].into_iter()
        .map(|a| a.as_str())
        .collect())
}
```

This will map elements from `&String` into `&str`, which can be collected likewise.

Comment: But in my code, first error is propagated as soon as it occurs. i.e. no more further calls are called for making tea. i.e. if `get_milk_from_cow` fails `pour_milk` will not be called. I think this is what `?` is for. I think this is not what will happen in your vec solution.

Comment: @AshishNegi That is true. You should consider improving your question to avoid further confusion.

Comment: You're better-off using `[&get_milk_from_cow(true)?, &pour_milk(true)?].concat()`, since it's shorter and preallocates.

Comment: @Veedrac That seems to be provided from the unstable trait `SliceConcatExt`, which I would prefer not to use.

Comment: @E_net4 ["The methods themselves are stable, but the trait isn't."](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27747), since August 2015.